# configure wso2 identity to generate JWT using OIDC/oauth

Tags: wso2-identity-server

can anyone assist me here . I am trying to use WSO2 to authenticate a user from active directory and  return a OIDC/oauth jwt token .

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details on where you are stuck and which version of component you try to configure.

There is three steps to get this done:

0 - Set email field as login : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username

1 - ConfigureAD as primary store in WSO2IS : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-Write+Active+Directory+User+Store

2 - Set up an OIDC client in WSO2IS : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On

3 - Configure your client to use WSo2IS as OIDC token provider

Jeff

Comment: Hi Jeff  I have configured WSO2 to generate JWT . What i am stuck with is , I would like to use Active directory for authenticating a user and then generate a JWT . How do i consume AD to generate JWT is not clear .

Comment: 1rst Q : Were you able to generate JWT in the default configuration ? If not go to https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On

2nd Q : Do you successfully authenticate to WSO2 Carbon using AD ? If not go to : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-Write+Active+Directory+User+Store

3nd Q : If two steps above have done successfully, what is the current error message you are seeing? where? what were you trying to do at the moment the error message popped up?

Comment: Hi Jeff I dont have a custom grant . I want to use resource owner password grant using email addres and password instead of username and password

Comment: eg: if i use following :curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic QTBZM1ZkQkYxbnFmSVVaazc4ZFduakN6NlRjYTpHbkROaUp6MTZqeFEwVDcwbVNXNkh2b21pZ2th" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin" https://10.4.183.16:9443/oauth2/token      i can generate an access token

Comment: But if i use :curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic QTBZM1ZkQkYxbnFmSVVaazc4ZFduakN6NlRjYTpHbkROaUp6MTZqeFEwVDcwbVNXNkh2b21pZ2th" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin@wso2.com&password=admin" https://10.4.183.16:9443/oauth2/token      -- i gives me {"error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid","error":"invalid_grant"}

Comment: following this i would like to use AD as data store to authenticate . I have configured AD as per https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-Write+Active+Directory+User+Store

Comment: see my comment on my answer. For email as login, you need to configure it, this is not default configuration

Comment: I Have followed the document  from wso2 to configure email as username but still didnt work